# Pivoting data with duplicate date values for differing id values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I have a `pd.DataFrame` that looks like the following below:

```
df

   id      date     price                        
0   1   31-08-2000  118.0 
1   2   31-08-2000  115.0 
2   1   01-09-2000  114.0  
3   2   01-09-2000  113.0  
4   3   01-09-2000  114.0  
5   4   01-09-2000  118.0  
6   1   02-09-2000  115.0  
7   2   02-09-2000  114.0  
8   3   02-09-2000  113.0  
9   4   02-09-2000  114.0
```

However, I want the `pd.DataFrame` to look like the following:

```
df
               1       2      3      4  
date
31-08-2000   118.0   115.0   NaN    NaN
01-09-2000   114.0   113.0  114.0  118.0 
02-09-2000   115.0   114.0  113.0  114.0
```

I have tried using `pd.pivot_table` but I cannot seem to get it to look like how I want it. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='id', values='price')` not working?

Comment: Can you be more specific why not working?

Comment: When I pivot, it does not start from the correct date. For example, my dataset starts with the date column ranging from 31-08-2000 until 31-12-2019, but when I do the pivot, all values before 20-01-2002 are not included

Comment: hmmm, are datetime like strings? If convert them to datetimes by `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)` before pivot, it working?

Comment: Ahhh, yes. That was the issue. Thanks for that!